# no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django

problem solved:
as i deleted all the migrations to check another error and then i forget to migrate

i was trying to login but is is showing this error after entering username and password but it is showing following error

**no such table: auth_user**

my forms.py

```
from django import forms

class login_form(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import login_form
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout

def login_view(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=login_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u_name= form.cleaned_data['username']
            passwrd= form.cleaned_data['password']
            user=authenticate(username=u_name,password=passwrd)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                else:
                    print('the  account has been disabled')
            else:
                print ("the username or password is incorrect" )
    else:
        form=login_form()
        return render(request,'users/login.html',{'form' :form})
```

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'memeroom.apps.MemeroomConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

what should i do now

Comment: Did you migrate the database?

Comment: yes i did already

Comment: did it show it created the user table in the database? Can you see the user table in the database?

Comment: how will i check, as i know after creating project user table get already created

Comment: you op en a database shell, and query for a list with tables, for example `SHOW TABLES` on a MySQL database.

Comment: you can execute `python manage.py dbshell`  to open a connection with the database, then try a `select * from auth_user;` to see if it returns something

Comment: it is showing there **You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.**

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to migrate the databases after deleting all the migrations so below two would work fine

```
python manage.py makemigrartions
python managepy migrate
```

even if it is saying no changes detected